NLog config file - pull value from WebConfig/App service config
.Net Framework 4.8 application running on an App Service.
(The project currently has all below Nuget packages installed for NLog)
NLog 4.7.15
NLog.Config 4.5.9
NLog.Extended 4.5.9
NLog.Web 4.6.0
NLog.Schema 4.5.9

So say we have a value in the app settings and connection string of  web.config
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ElasticUrl" connectionString="http://localhost:9200"/>
  </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="testRobot" value="12345" />
        </appSettings>

My question is it is possible to obtain these values inside the NLog.config file
So for example in the Nlog file we are setting the date with
  <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date}" />

is it possible to say something like
  <parameter name="@logged" layout="${ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testRobot"]}" />

thanks for any replies
UPDATE
Thank you to @Harshitha and @Rolf Kristensen for taking the time to reply.
I was able to get it working (for appsettings value) but with a slight different to what is suggested in the documentation where they use 'item' to retrieve the contents but I had to use 'name'
https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AppSetting-Layout-Renderer
 <parameter name="@message" layout="${appsetting:name=testRobot:default=default}" />

will store the value 12345 in the message.
However, this did not work for connection string...which according to the documentation (link just provided) if I have a
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MyKey" value="MyApplication" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ElasticUrl" connectionString="http://localhost:9200"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

I should be able to say:
${appsetting:item=connectionStrings.ElasticUrl}

this did not work, failing with:
Required parameter 'Name' on 'Layout Renderer: ${appsetting}' was not specified.
nor did:
 ${appsetting:name=connectionStrings.ElasticUrl}

which didnt throw an exception but saved the message as an empty string value??
and also just an observation but why are we using $(appsetting when the connection string values arnt inside the appsetting tag
any help please?

How you are retrieving the Date value from NLog?

See ${appsetting} and there is also a List of available Layout Renderers

Refer this SOThread once

Iam able to retrieve the value of appsetting by adding the appsetting in target section <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${appsetting:item=TestRobot:default=mydefault}" /> Image

AFAIK, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings in nlog file is not supported.

@Harshitha thank you for the reply I was able to get it working for appsettings with a slight change using 'name' instead of 'item', but I cant get it working for connection string, please see UPDATE of original post, thanks again

Are you still looking for sol with appsetting

You pointed me on the right path I was able to get the value for the appSetting but not for the connectionstring, please see UPDATE

How you are retrieving it in code?

by code you mean C#? I dont need it in C#...I have the appSetting value and now I need the ConnectionString value....both stored in web.config...and I need to access them in the NLog.Config file

@John Notice that you must use NLog v4.6.5 (or newer) to resolve ConnectionStrings-values.

@John Also notice that you should remove nuget-package NLog.Extended from your project when upgrading to NLog v4.6.5

You can use ${appsetting}, see also List of available Layout Renderers
${appsetting:name=testRobot:default=default}

Notice when using NLog v4.6.5 (or newer), then one can also resolve ConnectionStings-values like this:
${appsetting:item=connectionStrings.ElasticUrl}

And retrieve value from app.config-file like this:
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MyKey" value="MyApplication" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ElasticUrl" connectionString="http://localhost:9200"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Make sure to remove nuget-package NLog.Extended from your application-project when upgrading to NLog v4.6.5 (or newer).

Thank you for your help you have helped me to solve this issue, I also needed to do what you suggested in the comments and remove the N.Log.Extended in order for this to work, and use 'name' instead of 'item'
